# How to find a cube root of big numbers (22000) by approximation or factor method?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to find out cube root of number 22000 the exam which I am preparing provide us very less time. So here I can simply assume it will be between 20-30 but I can't multiply all numbers in the exam hall. Is there any idea to get cube root of this number through factors $2^4×5^3×11$. By checking 21,22,23 multiply three times is a big task in the less time. So i am trying to know any other method

Comment: Will you be asked for an approximation? If so, you can just use some benchmarks and use the expansion for $(a+b)^3$ to help.

Comment: Well clearly $22000=22\times10^3$. How accurate do you need it and how much time do you have? It should also be easy to check that $25^3=15625$ is way too small, and $30^3=27000$ is way too big. As $22000$ is roughly in the middle and $x^3$ is increasingly increasing, the cube root should be greater than $\tfrac{25+30}{2}=27.5$. I'd guess $28$ should be pretty close.

Comment: $(a+b)^3 $is  time taking too. We are given only 2 minutes to solve this kind of problems @SeanRoberson show me how will you use this cube formula in this how will you select a, b randomly and then multiply it in the mean time. I will give you -50 points for this suggestion. Read the question carefully first

Comment: Can we not find the cube root by factor method?  And who is the guy who gave -1 rating without knowing the complexities in this problem

Comment: Can you approximate using calculus?

Comment: @AndrewChin how to use it. It seems interesting

Comment: To what precision do you need to compute the cube root?

Comment: So that I can assume it's between two numbers e.g. 27-28. I want to know this level of approximation only @ser

Comment: It seems to be around $28$, might be slightly larger. See my earlier comment; this should take no more than 30 seconds. Computing $28^3$ may take another 30 seconds or so?

Comment: Yes. But finding first 25×25×25 and then mean is not a good solution of approximation even it's helpful but I am trying to know any other method too. Tell me please what is calculus can help in it

Comment: Why? If you know your tables, computing $25^3$ should take no more than 10 seconds.

Comment: As I have asked to many people. Cube of 1-10 is memorable or rest numbers is only guessed like I said above it lays between 20-30

Comment: I don't care whoever rated minus on a good question

Comment: Difference between cubes of two consecutive number is 1 more than 3 times their product. This is also useful while getting approximation. Suppose we have got 30 cube is 27000 now we can assume this trick and get it will be between 28-29. 30000-3×29×30-1 =24389 now again 24389-3×28×29-1=21952. I hope it helps quickly. Hats off to those guys who voted minus and closed a valuable discussion. This is the relation between two cubic numbers. Due to this I couldn't reply because no reputation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take your example, and I'll show that by some careful selection, you can use $(a +b)^3 = a^3 + 3a^2b +3ab^2 + b^3$ to approximate a cube root. This is naive, but it can get you started.

First note that $3^3 = 27,$ so $30^3 = 27000.$ You can now guess that the cube root of $22000$ is less than $30,$ and probably not by much. Now, in the above, let $a = 30$ and $b = -1$. A lot of the arithmetic is simplified, so

$$29^3 = (30 - 1)^3 = 30^3 - 2700 + 90 - 1 = 27000 - 2611 = 24389.$$

We're still too far away, so we use our new knowledge of $29^3$ so see if $28^3$ is closer, than we can refine our steps in halves.

TL:DR; If all you have is pencil and paper, then you're not going to have a foolproof way to do this "quickly." When using guess and check, you don't just select a "random" guess, but rather think smarter and choose something reasonable.

Comment: Is there any relation between two cube of numbers? I meant suppose cube of 25 =15625 what is minimum value should we add to it so we het next cube number? Is there any general term for it

Comment: No. Notice the gaps between cubes is not uniform. If you want the "pattern" then it's a matter of polynomial interpolation, but that is not the way you probably want.

Answer (score 0):

Since $22$ is closer to $27$ than to $8$, your cube root is close to $30$. So try your integers from $29$ downwards, not from $21$ upwards. You find with two trials that $22000$ is between $28^3$ and $29^3$, and much closer to the former.

Comment: @NawalKishoreverma $30^3+5000=20+\frac{5000}{3}\cdot900$ is not true. The whole formula doesn't hold because $A^3\pm B=A\pm B/3A^2$ is not true.

Comment: @DavidKrell 900 is multiplied with 3....i am beginner on mathjax that's why I uploaded a picture of it yesterday to not confused but they have deleted the picture. You can vote for undelete too

Comment: @NawalKishoreverma  You can use parantheses to indicate that. But besides that even $30^3+5000=20+\frac{5000}{3\cdot900}$ is not true. Even if we replace the $20$ with the correct $30$ it wouldn't be true. I will not vote for undelete because the picture yesterday was not helpful and provided in an answer which wasn't an answer.

Comment: @NawalKishoreverma Even $30^3-5000=30-\frac{5000}{3\cdot900}$ is not true.

Comment: So here is a formula which can give us close assumption of any big number. We just need to pick one cubic number close to given number the add/substrate left numbers and use the formula. It can tell us approximation into 1 minute. So I guess this is correct answer. It works for all numbers. I have not proved it. Anyone can use this formula for checking. A3±B=A±B/3A2
 Here we want to calculate 22000 so I'll first assume it's between 20-30 now I put values in the formula $30^3-5000=30-5000/3×900=28.14$
means it's pretty close to 28

Comment: This explains it's close to 28 and that's what i wanted